# How to change selected color for table view cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I select on a cell on my table view, it changes into this white color. I want to change it.

[image]

I tried using an if statement but it didn't work.

Here is the code that I used.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt 
indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)

    if cell.isSelected == true {
        cell.backgroundColor = .blue
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
    }

    return cell

}
```

Comment: What have you written in didSelectRow ?

Comment: What should you want? mean by tapping on tableViewCell that cell should be highlighted with different color & remain until user not select different cell    OR should only be highlight only when touch.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do either one of this -

1. Change the selectionStyle property of your cell.

For example: If you change it to UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray, it will be gray.

```
 cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
```

2. Change the selectedBackgroundView property.

   ```
   let bgColorView = UIView()
   bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
   cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView
   ```

swift 4 correction:

```
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.gray
```

Comment: `UITableViewCellSelectionStyle`  has been renamed to `UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle`

Comment: Swift 5 - cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none

Comment: or you can do just  "cell.selectionStyle = .gray"

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need this:

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView
```

Answer (score 2):

you can set the Selected Background view in awakeFromNib method

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
     override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            // Initialization code
            selectedBackgroundView = {
                let view = UIView.init()
                view.backgroundColor = .white
                return view
            }()
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do background color change in either your "willSelect" or "didSelect" method.
For example:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    cell.contentView.superview?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    return indexPath        
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your `UITableViewCell` class use following code for change selected cell background view color

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        if selected {
            self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        } else {
            self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }
    }
```